# How to solve $3/(x-4) + (x-3)/x =2$ for $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to solve the following for $x$?

$$3/(x-4) + (x-3)/x =2$$

Please don't avoid even the simplest steps. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2):

We start with: $\frac{3}{x-4}+\frac{x-3}{x}=2$.

We want to remove those denominators, so we multiply both sides by $x(x-4)$.

This gives $\frac{3x(x-4)}{x-4}+\frac{x(x-3)(x-4)}{x}=2x(x-4)$, which then simplifies to $3x+(x-3)(x-4)=2x(x-4)$.

We then expand out the multiplications. $3x$ is already simplified, $(x-3)(x-4)=x^2-7x+12$, and $2x(x-4)=2x^2-8x$. This is simply using the distributive property, also known as FOIL in some classes.

This gives us $3x+x^2-7x+12=2x^2-8x$. We subtract the terms on the left side from both sides (so that side will become zero). This gives $0=x^2-4x-12$. This can then be factored to $0=(x-6)(x+2)$, so either $0=x-6$ (in which case $x=6$), or $0=x+2$, in which case $x=-2$.

We can plug both of these back into the original equation and see that both work.

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{3}{x-4}$+$\frac{x-3}{x}$=$\frac{3x}{x(x-4)}$+$\frac{(x-4)(x-3)}{x(x-4)}$=$\frac{3x+(x-4)(x-3)}{x(x-4)}$=$\frac{3x+(x^2-7x+12)}{x(x-4)}$=$\frac{x^2-4x+12}{x(x-4)}$=2.

Then multiplying both sides by x(x-4) it follows that we obtain $x^2-4x+12$=$2x(x-4)$=$2x^2-8x$ so we can re-write moving all the terms on the right hand side $x^2-4x-12$=(x-6)(x+2)=0. This gives the solutions x=-2 and x=6.